# Catch a single element’s own deletion event

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, mutation-observers

I need to be notified of the deletion of a particular HTML DOM element.

I’m achieving this using a `MutationObserver`. To keep anything as simple as possible, I though it would be better to observe the target element for its own.

`MutationObserver` seems to not catch anything if it observes an element which gets itself deleted. Seems I have to `observe(element.parentElement, {childList: true})` to catch `element`’s own deletion, and `observe(element, {childList: true})` does not allow to catch it.

I noted `observe(element, {})` is not allowed since the WhatWG specification states “*If none of options’ childList, attributes, and characterData is true, throw a TypeError*”. But the same specification is not clear to me about whether or not `observe(element, {childList: true})` should catch `element`’s own deletion, although the former sentence implicitly suggest the answer to this is “no”.

Am I missing something about `MutationObserver.observe`? (I guess not, but better to ask). Am I wrong using `MutationObserver` to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an addition to your code.

Add `subtree: true` to options to make it look through all descendants.

> Beware to add the observer to the `document.body`, it can make your page hang. At least this happened when using the stack snippet.

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('some-id');
 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.removedNodes[0]);
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
var test = target.parentElement;
observer.observe(test , config);

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
   target.parentElement.removeChild(target);
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="some-id">
      test
  </div>
</div>

<button>change</button>
```

Comment: `subtree: true` is not needed, `childList: true` is enough, since direct children only are observed. Confirmed by my own script execution in Opera Developer.